# Resizing Google Maps MapView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, resize, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've attempted to use the code from the GoogleMapsSDKDemos to resize the mapview to a smaller rectangle on the screen, but it doesn't appear to have any effect. Here is my code:

mapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    mapView.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:38.98549782690282
                                                 longitude:-76.94636067188021
                                                      zoom:17];

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
mapView.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
mapView.frame = self.view.frame;
mapView.clipsToBounds = YES;
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView.settings.tiltGestures = NO;
mapView.settings.zoomGestures = NO;

mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 25);

[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
```

That second-to-last line seemingly should limit the MapView to just a small square, but it still takes up the entire screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
GMSCameraPosition* camera = [GMSCameraPosition 
    cameraWithLatitude: 38.98549782690282 
    longitude: -76.94636067188021 
    zoom: 17];
GMSMapView* mapView = 
    [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: GRectMake(0,0, 10, 25) camera: camera];
```

Note that the comments on the `GMSMapView` class in `GMSMapView.h` say:

> This class should not be instatiated directly, instead it must be
>   created with [GMSMapServices mapWithFrame:camera:]

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work, apparently my GMSServices.h file doesn't have that mapWithFrame method in it. I went back and checked the API and if you look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#add_a_map) it seems to use the GMMapView class? I'm not really sure, what you said would make sense but xcode can't find the mapWithFrame method in GMSServices (and neither can I)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I was going from that comment in the header, not from my own code. You need to call `mapWithFrame` on `GMSMapView`, not `GMSServices` (I guess that comment in the header is incorrect). I've updated my code above.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work for me, have you tried it yourself? I have `smallMap = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 25) camera: camera];` where smallmap is a GMMapView in a storyboard and it's still taking up the whole screen.

Comment: I create my UI programmatically, and passing a size to `mapWithFrame` works there. I haven't tried with a storyboard or xib.

Comment: I sort of solved the problem by just using a container view with the entire view controller inside of it. I doubt this is the most efficient solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add the map to the top of view:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                        longitude:longitude
                                                             zoom:10];



mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, width, height) camera:camera];
mapView_.delegate = self;
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```